# SQL- Need to Order By date first and then have a specific variable value always come first

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to order by results to order by date first but then to have a specific variable value (trackingbasisID=4) to always be ordered first. Below is an example. I have many variables in the select statement.I've also attached the graph of how results are shown. We'd liked to avoid the W in the graph s so we want the delay (TrackingBasisID=4) to always display first over all other id's but still sort by date first. My Current OrderBy Statement is simply:

```
ORDER BY hd.Date ASC, hd.PreimPhaseNumber ASC
```

[image: Current and Desired Result]

[image: Graph Example]

There are trackingbasis ID of 1,2,3,4,5,6 -- Of which We always want 4 to come first when being ordered.

Comment: The screenshot in your external link does not seem to agree with the text in your question.  Please _delete_ all external links from your question, and include all relevant data directly here.

Comment: I'm confused what isn't matching up? The only relevant variables I care about are PrimePhaseNumber, TrackingbasisID which does not display directly in the data, and date.

Comment: @AmandaSackett . . . There are small details such as the fact that your `order by` columns are not present in any of the data that you show.  Also, doing what you want seems to have nothing to do with the `order by`.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with a clearer explanation and better sample data.